# Field comments in ui_component form

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent

How do you create comments for fields in a **ui_component** **form**?

I can do it like this when building the form with php:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'url',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'url',
                'label' => __('URL'),
                'title' => __('URL'),
                'required' => false,
                'note' => 'Can be an absolute or relative path.'
            ]
        );
```

I can't find how to achieve this in an **xml form component**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use notice:

```
<item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
```

Full example:

```
<field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">model</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter full store name here</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: looks like notice does not support html tags. do you know any workaround?

Comment: @sergey, `<item name="additionalInfo" xsi:type="string" translate="true"><![CDATA[ .. <strong>Note</strong> : Enter note here with html tags.. ]]></item>` **additionalInfo** is alternate of **note** to **add comment or note**.